# Print numbers in two threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to print numbers from 0 to n in two threads. Even number in the first thread and odd numbers in the second.

**How can I print numbers with help of my code?**

Current output is

```
AAAA_1
AAAA_2
```

I expect for input 7:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I created a class

```
class PrintOrder {
private:
    int limit_;
    mutex m_;
    condition_variable cv_;
    int curNum_ = 0;
public:
    PrintOrder(int n) {
        limit_ = n;
        cout << "AAAA_1\n";
        cv_.notify_all();
        cout << "AAAA_2\n";
    }

    void even() {
        cout << "EVEN\n";
        while (curNum_ <= limit_) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lk(m_);
            cv_.wait(lk, [this]{return curNum_ % 2 == 0;});
            if (curNum_ <= limit_) {
                cout << curNum_ << endl;
                ++curNum_;
            }
            lk.unlock();
            cv_.notify_all();
        }
        return ;
    }

    void odd() {
        cout << "ODD\n";
        while (curNum_ <= limit_) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lk(m_);
            cv_.wait(lk, [this]{return curNum_ % 2 != 0;});
            if (curNum_ <= limit_) {
                cout << curNum_ << endl;
                ++curNum_;
            }
            lk.unlock();
            cv_.notify_all();
        }
        return ;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        cout << "ERROR: Expected console input" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    int num = atoi(argv[1]);
    PrintOrder printOrder(num);
}
```

I tried to create threads with functions odd() and evene() but functions should be static and it seems not my case

Comment: The logic of your program is already burning a race condition because of `while (curNum_ <= limit_)` *not* being protected by the mutex. That's what the mutex is for, incidentally: to protect the predicated data. You cannot write *or* read that concurrent data set without the mutex in place. When you decide to actually add *threads* to this you'll see that as the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reference, be it read or write, of data considered part of the predicate of a conditional state *must* be protected by the mutex intended for that purpose. That means *everywhere*, including the test conditions of your while loops.

Starting the threads is simple enough, just make sure you join them on destruction. The results look like the following code (which I took liberty to add a default `n=100` for, since I don't like typing command line arguments).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
using namespace std;

class PrintOrder final
{
private:
    int limit_;
    int curNum_;
    mutex m_;
    condition_variable cv_;
    std::thread thr_even, thr_odd;

public:
    PrintOrder(int n) 
        : limit_(n)
        , curNum_(0)
    {
        thr_even = std::thread(&PrintOrder::even, this);
        thr_odd = std::thread(&PrintOrder::odd, this);
    }

    ~PrintOrder()
    {
        thr_even.join();
        thr_odd.join();
    }

    void even()
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lk(m_);
        while (curNum_ <= limit_)
        {
            cv_.wait(lk, [this] { return curNum_ % 2 == 0; });
            if (curNum_ <= limit_)
            {
                cout << curNum_ << endl;
                ++curNum_;
            }
            cv_.notify_all();
        }
    }

    void odd()
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lk(m_);
        while (curNum_ <= limit_)
        {
            cv_.wait(lk, [this] { return curNum_ % 2 != 0; });
            if (curNum_ <= limit_)
            {
                cout << curNum_ << endl;
                ++curNum_;
            }
            cv_.notify_all();
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int num = 100;
    if (argc == 2)
        num = std::stoi(argv[1]);

    PrintOrder printOrder(num);
}
```

The output is what you would expect: the numbers 1 through 100, one per line, in order.

Comment: Your code is more reasonably organized than mine, glad to see it.

Answer (score 2):

`curNum_` needs to be protected by mutex or we can simply switch to an atomic number, then spawn 2 threads in the constructor to call `even` `odd` respectively, the output is what you expected.

For the call member function in the thread, we don't need a static function, just capture `this` will be fine.

We don't need the last `return;` statement, so I removed it.

Tips:

[Thread sanitizers](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) will help your stay from data races.

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class PrintOrder final {
 private:
  int limit_;
  mutex m_;
  condition_variable cv_;
  std::atomic_int curNum_{0};

 public:
  PrintOrder(int n) {
    limit_ = n;
    cv_.notify_all();
    std::thread thr1([this] { even(); });
    std::thread thr2([this] { odd(); });

    thr1.join();
    thr2.join();
  }

  void even() {
    while (curNum_ <= limit_) {
      unique_lock<mutex> lk(m_);
      cv_.wait(lk, [this] { return curNum_ % 2 == 0; });
      if (curNum_ <= limit_) {
        cout << curNum_ << endl;
        ++curNum_;
      }
      lk.unlock();
      cv_.notify_all();
    }
  }

  void odd() {
    while (curNum_ <= limit_) {
      unique_lock<mutex> lk(m_);
      cv_.wait(lk, [this] { return curNum_ % 2 != 0; });
      if (curNum_ <= limit_) {
        cout << curNum_ << endl;
        ++curNum_;
      }
      lk.unlock();
      cv_.notify_all();
    }
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    cout << "ERROR: Expected console input" << endl;
    return -1;
  }
  int num = atoi(argv[1]);
  PrintOrder printOrder(num);
}
```

Comment: If you start threads in the constructor - make the class `final` to not get nasty surprises when trying to inherit the class.

Comment: This *still* has the race condition active on both `while` clauses. No manual locks and unlocks should be required. scope locking before both `while` loops *start* is all that is needed.

Comment: @WhozCraig Could you please elaborate more? I can't see any data race here, I have checked it with thread sanitizer and also get no errors.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin easier to just look at the difference between your post and mine. In purest simplicity, just ask yourself these two questions: (1) What mutable data is considered part of the conditional predicate, and (2) is ALL said-data access (write *and* read) from (1) properly protected under the latch of the mutex associated with said condition?

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you so much I have compared with your code, but in my code, I have turned the `curNum_ ` into an atomic number, do we still have a data race here?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin no, there would be no data race in this specific case.

Comment: the atomic still seems a waste, as it is costly and only read adjacent to a mutex lock/unlock.  Also fragile, as rewriting as 3 way printer the naive way gets you a data race again.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont `as rewriting as 3 way printer the naive way gets you a data race again`, Can you explain in more detail? I haven't seen any races.

Answer (score 0):

I find the other answers are making it overly complex for no reason. You simply need an atomic counter, two threads, and simple direct conditions:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

std::atomic<int> count;

void even(int limit)
{
    while(true)
    {
        int value = count;
        if (value >= limit)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (value % 2)
        {
            std::cout << value << std::endl;
            count++;
        }
    }
}

void odd(int limit)
{
    while(true)
    {
        int value = count;
        if (value >= limit)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (!(value % 2))
        {
            std::cout << value << std::endl;
            count++;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::thread thread1(even, 20);
    std::thread thread2(odd, 20);

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    
    return 0;
}
```

The atomic int guarantees it will all work nicely, because for each value only one thread will try to write(increment) concurrently. The only place to care a bit around multithreading is to be careful to do a single read in each thread iteration with:

```
int value = count;
```

But for this simple a problem, no need for mutices and fancy synchronization.

Comment: Fair warning: "Work nicely" is in the eye of the beholder. Sans mutual concurrency modelling, you've written what is known as spin-loops (also called "spin-polling"). How many times will the "odd" loop cycle needlessly before the "even" loop finally finishes its output and incrementing the counter, and vice versa? [A lot](https://ideone.com/IAs2UI).

Comment: @whozcraig I worked in low latency systems. I'll trade cpu usage for speed/latency any day :-). But yeah, YMMV if you do that on a mobile platform and want to save battery